# Is this python logging module bug while using TimedRotatingFileHandler and rollover by hour?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Using python logging module class TimedRotatingFileHandler. The class check should rollover use below,

```
def shouldRollover(self, record):
    t = int(time.time())
    if t >= self.rolloverAt:
        return 1
    return 0
```

and it compute next rollover time by using

```
def doRollover(self): 
    currentTime = int(time.time())
    newRolloverAt = self.computeRollover(currentTime)
    self.rolloverAt = newRolloverAt
def computeRollover(self, currentTime):
    result = currentTime + self.interval
```

For example, if process started at 2016/03/01 19:33:00, then the self.rolloverAt first set to 2016/03/01 20:00:00, but may no log to write until 2016/03/01 20:00:05, so the first rollover will happen at 20:00:05, and set the newRolloverAt to 2016/03/01 21:00:05, then the next all rollover will not happen at the begin of one hour.

Comment: Where does it say that the rollovers are to happen *exactly on the hour*? The rollover has to happen after that much time has passed. If the log is less busy, you don't need to roll over as often.

Comment: So if there are *no log entries at all* until `20:59:50`, there is no point in rolling over *again* 10 seconds later.

Comment: Yes, It's just not happen at the begin of one hour. And after some days, it may rollover with a  large offset from the begin of one hour, for example 15:30:00.

Comment: You'll see that for `MIDNIGHT` or weekday roll-overs, a more specific rollover time is calculated; for intervals you want to avoid *too many* rollovers.

Comment: Yeah, I can see than MIDNIGHT or weekday roll-overs have a more specific rollover time, But why not support hour roll-over ? If has not support specific rollover time for hour roll-over, why it can set hour roll-over option?

Comment: What would the advantage be? Use the UNIX `logrotate` facility then to do the rotating for you; it runs at specific times rather than by log events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. This is by design instead. If you adhere to exact intervals from the starting time, you can end up with erratic roll-overs. If your app is quiet until shortly before the next 'fixed' rollover time, you'd get two new files closely together (one created at 5 seconds before the hour, the next at the hour, for example).

So for the interval types `S`, `M`, `H` and `D`, sparse logging will result in a new interval starting when the next log entry comes in. That way you still get a full duration before the next rotation.

An exception is made for `midnight` and the `W0` .. `W6` weekday rotations; just below the code you found it makes a precise calculation for the next midnight (of the correct weekday if needed) for the next rollover. That's because these intervals *do* imply a specific time in the day. And with *whole days* for logging to take place, a last-minute log entry before a rotation point is far less of a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand that "you'fd get two new files closely together", why it happened?

Comment: @ccwenlin: say nothing is logged for nearly an hour. You log an entry at 5 seconds before the next interval would start, then continue with some more logs. Why rotate after 5 seconds when you reach the next hour?

Comment: @ccwenlin: so logging takes place until 20:50 in the previous rotation, then starts again at 21:59. The 20:00-21:00 rotation is taken care of, a new file is  started. Why use a new file for 21:00-22:00, when you only have at most 1 minute of log data in that rotation?

Comment: @ccwenlin: rotating like these results in fewer files, each holding up to a whole hour of logs. They just don't start on the whole hour.

Comment: even only have at most 1 minute of log data in that rotation, I still want to rotate it at the starting time. so I want to know what risk I will face if I adhere to do it.

Comment: @ccwenlin: you'd have to create a subclass of the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` class with a custom `computeRollover` method that implements your desired logic.

Answer (score 1):

Realy this TimedRotatingFileHandler from logging API doesn't support the behavior expected by you (and by me).
I see the sources, and I guess it was bad design, then it's very difficult to adjust without workaround to having the behavior.
In Java, the log4j support this behavior without problems, and until now I can't find another Python API that does it.

But I did a workaround class works like as [TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html) from [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender):

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

class SyncTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when='h', backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None):
        TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, filename, when=when, interval=1, backupCount=backupCount, encoding=encoding, delay=delay, utc=utc, atTime=atTime)    

    def computeRollover(self, currentTime):
        currentTime = currentTime if (self.when == 'MIDNIGHT' or self.when.startswith('W')) else currentTime - (int(currentTime) % self.interval)
        return TimedRotatingFileHandler.computeRollover(self, currentTime)
```

And to test:

```
logger = logging.Logger('myLogger')
handler = SyncTimedRotatingFileHandler('synctime.log', 'M', 0, 'UTF-8', False, False, None)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
c = 0
while (True):
  c += 1
  logger.info("Logger Test " + str(c))
  time.sleep(1)
```